# How do i install Nvidia geforce GTX 460 on a fresh 12.10 Installation?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.10, graphics

I've installed Ubuntu on my computer for the first time, so I'm an Ubuntu-noob. Can anyone please tell me how I install my gfx? I've tried to install it by using some guides, but I can't do it the right way. My launcher disappeared and my resolution dropped. Can anyone post me an exact guide to my problem?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218629/driver-for-graphics-card

Answer (score 4):

I guess you better take a look over here first
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-using.html,
before adding those PPA listed in the guide remember to uninstall your previous Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Welcome to AU! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for reference. Read more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should install [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html). More information at the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation).

Cheers

Comment: Read the *updated* instructions in [this page](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Upgrading-on-Ubuntu) :-)

Comment: Why would the OP need bumblebee *at all*?

Comment: i get this message, when i have to add myself as a user.

usermod: group 'bumblebee' does not exist

Comment: UPDATE!

Ubuntu says Driver :VESA: BIOS-P/N@N7211
but my monitor is now degraded to Laptop with a max res on 1024x768.

Comment: And now after Rebooting again, empty desktop and no unity. What to do ??

Comment: What I have done is the following: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia && sudo gpasswd -a $USER bumblebee`

Comment: DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match System manufacturer with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match System manufacturer with Dell Inc.
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match

And I'm now back with: Ubuntu says Driver :VESA: BIOS-P/N@N7211 but my monitor is now degraded to Laptop with a max res on 1024x768.